# Get first heading tag from parent / parents dynamically using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I get the first parent in dom tree (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) ? Using a recursive function or anything else. I'm trying to get the first h1 to h6 that exists when user clicks an anchor the big problem that I have is that I don't have classes I need to detect in someway the first heading tag dynamically.

For example:

```
<h2>Example of Heading</h2>
<h2>I need the first heading from the child to parent</h2>
<div>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text here
<a>Click here</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: In jQuery you can use [the `.closest()` method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Note however that in your own example the `<h2>` is not a *parent* of any other element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried with $(this).closest(":header").text() for example and return null...

Comment: well because none of the parents are headers....

Comment: You'd want something like `$(this).closest("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6")` but again in the example posted that won't return any header elements because they're not parents in the DOM tree.

Comment: It is not an easy thing to do because we do not know if there is a guaranteed structure. If there was a certain structure it could be done. If not, you are writing something that walks up the tree looking.

Comment: I understand, this is why I need some help, to detect in someway the first h1 to h6 that I have up in the DOM either is a parent or not but to be the first heading before the child

Comment: so climb up the tree looking at prev siblings and parent siblings.

Comment: Can you give me a example please of code please?

Comment: I do not have time to code it for you since I have a job to also do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName is basically what you have to look at. jQuery would be prev() and parent()

Comment: Thank you sir :) I will take a look